# The options [useMongoClient] is not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongodb-3.6.0.

My express code is

```
var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

On running the app I am getting `the options [useMongoClient] is not supported`. My mongoose version in `^5.0.0-rc0`.

Please help.

Comment: Oh wow, so this *is* a new issue. A few months ago, I added that line to my projects no problem. I guess the latest mongoose update deprecated that line for now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is not much documentation about this yet as Mongoose 5 is in release candidate stage but with mongoose 5 you don't need to provide useMongoClient option. Mongoose 5 is using Mongo client by default. So just remove this option.

Answer (score 7):

mongoose 5 doesn't require useMongoClient anymore.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/DB_name');
```

is enough.
You can check for the documentation of "Mongoose 5" [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is pretty simple just remove `{ useMongoClient: true }` flag from your code since the option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x and use 
`{ useNewUrlParser: true }` since you might get a message that the current URL string parser is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/qunar', { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
module.exports = mongoose
```

answer:☟

Delete the first line of code `{ useMongoClient: true }` and then restart the server

Answer (score 0):

No Need of `useMongoClient` Flag Now with Newer version of mongoose.

```
{ 
    useMongoClient : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me node.js v14 + mongoose v6

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/your-db-name", {
  auth: {
    username: "user",
    password: "password",
  },
  authSource: "admin",
});
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful. What is `authSource`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).